# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mayank.sunshine.SettingsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.mayank.sunshine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings.
 * <p>
 * See <a href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html">
 * Android Design: Settings</a> for design guidelines and the <a
 * href="http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html">Settings
 * API Guide</a> for more information on developing a Settings UI.
 */
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceFragment
        implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

        // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
        // updated when the preference changes.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
    }

    /**
     * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
     * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
     * is changed.)
     */
    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
            }
        } else {
            // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The above code shows the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mayank.sunshine.SettingsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

The code previously had "SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity", but some of the functions are shown as deprecated, and I was guided to use the PreferenceFragment class instead, so on changing the parent class, the error started popping up. Also, the following part of manifest file shows error in android:name=".SettingsActivity"

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.mayank.sunshine.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Post the actual error message. It doesn't seem to be happening in this piece of code.

Comment: @Simas: I believe the error lies in the manifest file. Please have a look at the update.

Comment: Since it's no longer an activity, it shouldn't be in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above code shows the following error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mayank.sunshine.SettingsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

That is because your `SettingsActivity` does not have `Activity` in its inheritance chain. `SettingsActivity` inherits from `Fragment`, which inherits from `Object`.

> The code previously had "SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity", but this class is deprecated in newer APIs

`PreferenceActivity` is not deprecated in any version of Android, through API Level 23.

Comment: Oh sorry, not the class, but some of the functions like addPreferenceFromResource() are being shown as deprecated..

Comment: @MayankPanchal: Correct. "Deprecated" in Android means "we think we have a better solution that we would like for you to consider". In this case, it would be using a `PreferenceFragment` in a regular `Activity`.

Comment: @MayankPanchal: Well, I do not know where your exception is coming from. At the one comment on your answer notes, there is nothing obvious in your code that would raise this exception. However, you need to have an `Activity` somewhere that uses this fragment. If your manifest still has an `<activity>` element pointing to this class, that will not work, as this is not an `Activity`. Here is a sample app using a `PreferenceFragment` from an `Activity`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/Fragment.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for this information. Highly useful for me. Can you guide me how to use PreferenceFragment in this case?

Comment: I got your point. But I don't know how to implement it. I am following this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=2&v=MNDeAyxcQwc) and the gist being referred to is (https://gist.github.com/udacityandroid/41aca2eb9ff6942e769b)